# Map sequences of numbers to single characters in Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala

Given an input string map three types of possible sequences of numbers contained in the string to a single number and leave the other elements of the string unchanged:

1. Single number should be mapped to the char 1: "help3me" -> "help1me"
2. Two numbers in a row should be mapped to the char 2:  "help18me" -> "help2me"
3. Three or more numbers in a row should be mapped to 3:  "test3432help234312me" -> "test3help3me"

   Our input strings can contain any number of 1,2,3+ length sequences of digits so that a valid input example is "help3490897test73me23435please5"

   > What is an effective solution for the above problem in Scala does it just involve enumerating through the three possible cases as a regex ?

Comment: That looks like not a genuine practical problem, but some kind of test or homework. No problem to ask this on SO per se, just include the reference to the original, and mark the question, e.g. with the "homework" tag.

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expression and method `replaceAllIn`. The second argument is the function that takes [Match](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex$$Match) object and transforms it to its length.

```
val str =  "help3me34"
val expr = "(\\d+)".r
expr.replaceAllIn(str, x => (x.group(0).length min 3).toString)
res2: String = help1me2
```

Comment: Everything greater than 3 should be 3, so it should be: `x => (x.group(0).length min 3).toString`

Comment: Oh, yeah, i didn't read the question carefully. Thx! Anyway i hope teacher will ask him about finite automate and this answer doesn't help him much :)

Comment: I get what you mean, but don't forget that it's mostly real, professional programmers who use SO on a regular basis. So it doesn't hurt to pick up a bit of knowledge on how to use SO during university/school.